# Python Regex/Beautiful Soup Wild Card

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, regex-negation

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I couldn't find exactly how to do this and I am not the most experienced with regex of BeautifulSoup.

Basically, I have these lines of code.

```
finder = re.compile('div_\w\w\w_basic')
for soup_ in soup.find_all("div", {"id" : finder}):
```

This gives me all the div tags where some "div_###_basic" occurs.  Now, I want to save the results in a dictionary such that the keys are whatever the ### was, 
and the data is the information I'm scraping.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out my issue.  In case anyone else runs into it,

```
finder = re.compile('div_(\w\w\w)_basic')
print re.findall(finder, str(soup))
for soup_ in soup.find_all("div", {"id" : finder}):
```

This let me get the partial string in one point and the full string in another.  Once again, I'm pretty sure this isn't the best way to do it, but it is functional.

Comment: I guess you can also use `finder = re.compile('div_(\w{3})_basic')`.